# 2 Monero GUIs, 2 different balances

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I loaded 2 PCs with Monero GUI and use the same wallet on both.  5 of 6 transactions are the same and the balance is @1 XMR different.  For the 6th transaction, one wallet says I received 0.6 XMR, the other says an "unknown recipient" was sent .94 XMR.  How can I reconcile these transactions?  One is obviously wrong.  I looked at the check transaction feature but I don't seem to have all the right info from one GUI to input into the other.

Answer (score 0):

Which wallet is accurate? The one with 5 or 6 transactions? I would likely delete the GUI and the wallets. Reinstall the GUI and then recover the wallet from the seed but I'm not expert.

Comment: The one that says I paid to an "unknown recipient" is wrong. I was trying to avoid downloading the whole blockchain but I will if I have to